# CSS classes special characters and class prefixes behavior

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have got a template with CSS selectors that is making me wonder.

The sytax is as follows:

`.\35 grid .\31 1u { width: 91.5%; }`, the `'\'` is viewing in Notepad++ as a W crossed with a line. Can anyone tell me how this is interpreted? The class is being used as 5grid

Besides, i have noticed that a prefix for classes is being used "do-classX" knowing that when the class is used on an element, it is being set as `<element class="classX"></element>` and the styling is being applied, could there be a sort of mapping for class name? How is this being understood by the browser as the class where it is applying the styling?

This is freaking me out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS selectors are not allowed to start with a number. What you are seeing is a workaround where they are "escaping" the number to create a valid selector.

For example, with HTML like this:

```
<a class="9">Link</a>
```

You could select it like this:

```
.\39 {

}
```

Ben Frain has a really good article that goes into more detail: http://benfrain.com/when-and-where-you-can-use-numbers-in-id-and-class-names/

Comment: Thanks Steve. That was really benefitial. Any idea how the 'do-className'  is being used at the level of html without the prefix 'do-' and works fine??

Comment: @user2611451 That I am not sure about. If you post a larger example of that I may be able get a better idea.